# Description of Errors occured in creating the Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse

i am installing Android Api 19 but when i create the Android appliction this generates the follwing errors. Android is installad on windows 7.plz help me solving these errors of `"Build path"` i have updated the tools but these errors still occuring.

Description Resource Path Location Type

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\Workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar' Test  Build path Build Path Problem
```

Description Resource Path Location Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved Test  Unknown Java Problem

Comment: do you have the support library and repository under 'extras' in the sdk manager installed?

Comment: search for this file `appcompat_v7.jar` in your `sdk` folder and put it in the `libs` folder of your app and recompile :-/

Comment: i have checked but not found appcompat_V7.jar in sdk. and both the Support library and repository under 'extras'.